# Swagger-ui Spring Security and OAuth2 project Logout button doesn't clean Session cookies

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, swagger-2.0

I am working for microservice (rest API) with Spring boot, security and OAuth2  project with swagger 2.

Although it's a Rest service project but it creates a session cookie when a user login and after logout cookie should be removed and when any user tries to access the APIs need to put an access token again but the cookie remains the same.

So the same users can access API again without login after refreshing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
http
   .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
```

add this line on WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter bean It's work for me.

OR

For MVC:

```
.and()
.logout().clearAuthentication(true)
.logoutSuccessUrl("/")
.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID","remember-me")
.invalidateHttpSession(true)
.and()
```